# Tomcat 7 with UTF-8 encode

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets, utf-8, josso

Case 1: I have a virtual machine with Ubuntu and Tomcat 7.x. If i POST data with special characters to the server i'ts ok. I have a filter that run before any servlet and set the encode to UTF-8 `request.setCharacterEncoding("utf-8");`

Case 2: In the same virtual machine i have other Tomcat 7.x installation (reply). Now i installed the JOSSO 1.8.6 on Tomcat 7.x. After this when i try to submit POST data with special characters the servlet don't decode correctly `request.getParameter("reportText");`.

I believe that the JOSSO have any filter that run before my Encode Filter and uses the request what makes my filter `request.setCharacterEncoding("utf-8")` useless.

What i try to resolve the problem:

- I have set the URIEncoding="utf-8" at the Tomcat Connector tag (server.xml).
- I have used setCharacterEncoding().
- I have set the `JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -Djavax.servlet.request.encoding=UTF-8 -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8"` on tomcat setenv.sh
- I checked the HTTP Headers and they are correct (Content-Type=text/plain;charset=utf-8)
- I have enable Tomcat filter `setCharacterEncodingFilter`

The POST request is generated by client JSP

```
<form id="xx" name="xx" onsubmit="return validateAndSubmitForm(this);" action="submitReport.do" method="post" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset: utf-8;"> xxx </form>
```

My JSP tag on top:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
```

POST headers:
[image with the headers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pyu75.jpg)

Any ideas?
Thank you.

Comment: This is unclear.  The character encoding is set by the client browser that initiates the POST request, and the character encoding should be included in the request.  What is generating the POST request? Is the client not adding the correct encoding header such that you need to add it upon receipt? If that is the case, it is quite possible JOSSO is reading a request parameter, which turns your call to `request.setCharacterEncoding` into a no-op (according to the Javadoc).  The problem here seems to be that your client does not set the encoding correctly.  Please clarify.

Comment: I edit my post. The POST request is generated by JSP page with form.

Comment: I read this page https://wiki.apache.org/tomcat/FAQ/CharacterEncoding and i follow your suggestions but without success when have JOSSO installed on tomcat.

Answer (score 2):

I added the `URIEncoding` attribute of the `Connector` element of the `server.xml` file which is the configuration file of tomcat.

My code is the following.

```
<Connector URIEncoding="UTF-8" connectionTimeout="20000" port="8082" protocol="HTTP/1.1" redirectPort="8443"/>    
<Connector URIEncoding="UTF-8" port="8009" protocol="AJP/1.3" redirectPort="8443"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

The solution that work for me is add URIEncoding to server.xml file into of ubuntu configuration.

```
<Connector URIEncoding="UTF-8" connectionTimeout="20000" port="8082" protocol="HTTP/1.1" redirectPort="8443"/>    
<Connector URIEncoding="UTF-8" port="8009" protocol="AJP/1.3" redirectPort="8443"/>
```